# Use gzip File Locally

Tags: gzip, browser-sync

I've got a compressed gzip file in my site directory. I've never worked with gzip, but it doesn't seem like it works on a local machine.

I'm spinning up a local server with BrowserSync to view my site, how can I get the browser to read my `main.css.gz` file?

Any help with this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the middleware hook of the browserSync config where you check for a certain filetype (in your case `.gz`) and set the appropriate Content-Encoding and Content-Type Headers for the delivery

```
  {
    'browsersync': {
        'taskName': {
            'options': {
                'server': {
                    'middleware': [
                        function (req, res, next) {
                            if(req._parsedUrl.pathname.match(/\.gz$/g)){
                              res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
                              res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
                            }
                            next();
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it's not best practice to rely on _parsedUrl variable (since the underscore declares it as private) and you should use `url` instead, but for the sake of simplicity, I'll stick with it.